# How can we create a common component that can be used across the pages for drupal-8 structure for a multipage website?

Tags: content-management-system, drupal-8

If a multi-page website has different styling on different pages, how can we create a common component that can be used across the pages for drupal structure. As, when we select a component to be inserted in a page, it comes with its own classes. To manage those classes, we need to create separate CSS file for each page. Can't we have a common component which can be used across the website.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways to accomplish what you have outlined here. I would recommend using blocks.

Blocks can be added to whatever pages you need based upon the content type or specific paths. Any styling you need to target that block should be added to a CSS file imported by a global library in your theme.

Resources:

- [Managing Blocks in Drupal 8](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/block/overview)
- [Attaching a library to all pages](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-theme#attach-library-all-pages)